# Nuxt 3 development / production environments

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I'm trying to setup development / production environments in Nuxt 3. The reason is for some testing. If the app url starts with develop- , staging- , or test- I want to use a test endpoint such as https://develop-www.app.com/. I have my nuxt config setup and it's working when I am running locally and in prod by creating the variable based off the NODE env. However when in any of the test environments mentioned before the app is using the PROD endpoint as it does not know it's an a development environment. Is there a way to set that up based on the NODE env?

```
nuxt config

const isProdEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const testServicesEndpoint =
  'https://test-services.location';
const prodServicesEndpoint =
  'https://services.prodlocation';
const servicesEndpoint = isProdEnv
  ? prodServicesEndpoint
  : testServicesEndpoint;


export default defineNuxtConfig({
     runtimeConfig: {
        public: {
          apiBase: servicesEndpoint,
        },
      },
})
```

I created a generateTest action that would run in github actions if the branch was not equal to main which I thought would work but the build is showing this error:

[warn] Changing `NODE_ENV` from `development` to `production`, to avoid unintended behavior.

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "generateTest": "NODE_ENV=development nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

When the Nuxt is building the `dist`, it won't know the current domain because there is no request sent to the Nuxt.

---

Multiple `.env` files may meet your needs.

For example, in your Nuxt project root dir

```
.env.test
.env.stage
.env.prod
.env
```

specifically the `ENV` in `package.json`

[custom-file for `.env`](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/env#custom-file)

```
    "scripts": {
        "build": "nuxt build",
        "dev": "nuxt dev",
        
        // for different env variables
        "dev:test": "nuxt dev --dotenv .env.test", // run with .env.test
        "dev:stage": "nuxt dev --dotenv .env.stage", // run with .env.stage
        
        "generate": "nuxt generate",
        "preview": "nuxt preview",
        "postinstall": "nuxt prepare",
        "lint": "eslint .",
        "lint:fix": "eslint . --fix",
        "prod": "node .output/server/index.mjs"
    },
```